# SciPy Curve Fit Fails Power Law

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

So, I'm trying to fit a set of data with a power law of the following kind:

```
def f(x,N,a): # Power law fit
    if a >0:
        return N*x**(-a)
    else:
        return 10.**300

par,cov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f,data,time,array([10**(-7),1.2]))
```

where the else condition is just to force a to be positive. Using scipy.optimize.curve_fit yields [an awful fit (green line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z4yk.png), returning values of 1.2e+04 and 1.9e0-7 for N and a, respectively, with absolutely no intersection with the data. From fits I've put in manually, the values should land around 1e-07 and 1.2 for N and a, respectively, though putting those into curve_fit as initial parameters doesn't change the result. Removing the condition for a to be positive results in a worse fit, as it chooses a negative, which leads to a fit with the wrong sign slope.

I can't figure out how to get a believable, let alone reliable, fit out of this routine, but I can't find any other good Python curve fitting routines. Do I need to write my own least-squares algorithm or is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: welcome to SO, great first question.  Not sure why you got a silent downvote.

Comment: Always check `cov` when you use `curve_fit`.  What is `cov` when you get that really bad fit?

Comment: *"I can't find any other good Python curve fitting routines..."*  Take a look at `lmfit` (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/); in particular, see http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html

Comment: Note that in scipy 0.17, you can do a fit with bounds, which should be better than a non-smooth cutoff you're imposing.

Comment: Data in a power law are very different in different regions. I'd try to fit the `log` of your data.

Comment: I combined @WarrenWeckesser and roadrunner66 suggestions and added a solution below using lmfit. Let me know whether that solves your problem.

Comment: What is `data` and what is `time` ? didn't you swap them ?

Comment: @ev-br: Good point! I added an example on how to use it in my answer below.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: That is indeed the wrong way around, I think. I corrected that in the answer below.

Comment: @Cleb: Yes, sorry, I'm new to the site and set up email notifications for replies that I somehow never got... Just seeing these now. You're right, I just flipped the arguments, I'm getting much better fits now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

In the original post, I showed a solution that uses `lmfit` which allows to assign bounds to your parameters. Starting with version 0.17, scipy also allows to assign bounds to your parameters directly (see [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)). Please find this solution below after the **EDIT** which can hopefully serve as a minimal example on how to use scipy's `curve_fit` with parameter bounds.

**Original post**

As suggested by @Warren Weckesser, you could use [lmfit](http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/installation.html) to get this task done, which allows you to assign bounds to your parameters and avoids this 'ugly' if-clause.

Since you do not provide any data, I created some which are shown here:

[image]

They follow the law `f(x) = 10.5 * x ** (-0.08)`

I fit them - as suggested by @roadrunner66 - by transforming the power law in a linear function:

```
y = N * x ** a
ln(y) = ln(N * x ** a)
ln(y) = a * ln(x) + ln(N)
```

So I first use `np.log` on the original data and then do the fit. When I now use lmfit, I get the following output:

```
[[Variables]]
    lN:   2.35450302 +/- 0.019531 (0.83%) (init= 1.704748)
    a:   -0.08035342 +/- 0.005158 (6.42%) (init=-0.5)
```

So `a` is pretty close to the original value and `np.exp(2.35450302)` gives 10.53 which is also very close to the original value.

The plot then looks as follows; as you can see the fit describes the data very well:

[image]

Here is the entire code with a couple of inline comments:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit

# generate some data with noise
xData = np.linspace(0.01, 100., 50.)
aOrg = 0.08
Norg = 10.5
yData = Norg * xData ** (-aOrg) + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, len(xData))
plt.plot(xData, yData, 'bo')
plt.show()

# transform data so that we can use a linear fit
lx = np.log(xData)
ly = np.log(yData)
plt.plot(lx, ly, 'bo')
plt.show()

def decay(params, x, data):

    lN = params['lN'].value
    a = params['a'].value

    # our linear model
    model = a * x + lN
    return model - data # that's what you want to minimize

# create a set of Parameters
params = Parameters()
params.add('lN', value=np.log(5.5), min=0.01, max=100)  # value is the initial value
params.add('a', value=-0.5, min=-1, max=-0.001)  # min, max define parameter bounds

# do fit, here with leastsq model
result = minimize(decay, params, args=(lx, ly))

# write error report
report_fit(params)

# plot data
xnew = np.linspace(0., 100., 5000.)
# plot the data
plt.plot(xData, yData, 'bo')
plt.plot(xnew, np.exp(result.values['lN']) * xnew ** (result.values['a']), 'r')
plt.show()
```

**EDIT**

Assuming that you have scipy 0.17 installed, you can also do the following using `curve_fit`. I show it for your original definition of the power law (red line in the plot below) as well as for the logarithmic data (black line in the plot below). The data is generated in the same way as above. The plot the looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the data is described very well. If you print `popt` and `popt_log`, you obtain `array([ 10.47463426,   0.07914812])` and `array([ 2.35158653, -0.08045776])`, respectively (note: for the letter one you will have to take the exponantial of the first argument - `np.exp(popt_log[0]) = 10.502` which is close to the original data).

Here is the entire code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# generate some data with noise
xData = np.linspace(0.01, 100., 50)
aOrg = 0.08
Norg = 10.5
yData = Norg * xData ** (-aOrg) + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, len(xData))

# get logarithmic data
lx = np.log(xData)
ly = np.log(yData)

def f(x, N, a):
    return N * x ** (-a)

def f_log(x, lN, a):
    return a * x + lN

# optimize using the appropriate bounds
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, xData, yData, bounds=(0, [30., 20.]))
popt_log, pcov_log = curve_fit(f_log, lx, ly, bounds=([0, -10], [30., 20.]))

xnew = np.linspace(0.01, 100., 5000)

# plot the data
plt.plot(xData, yData, 'bo')
plt.plot(xnew, f(xnew, *popt), 'r')
plt.plot(xnew, f(xnew, np.exp(popt_log[0]), -popt_log[1]), 'k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: @CF84 I just picked some; you can choose any bounds you like.