# How to fit the following function using curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, scientific-computing

I have the following function I need to solve:

```
np.exp((1-Y)/Y) = np.exp(c) -b*x
```

I defined the function as:

```
def function(x, b, c):

    np.exp((1-Y)/Y) = np.exp(c) -b*x
    return y

def function_solve(y, b, c):

    x = (np.exp(c)-np.exp((1-Y)/Y))/b
    return x
```

then I used:

```
x_data = [4, 6, 8, 10]

y_data = [0.86, 0.73, 0.53, 0.3] 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(function, x_data, y_data,(28.14,-0.25))
answer = function_solve(0.5, popt[0], popt[1])
```

I tried running the code and the error was:

> can't assign to function call

The function I'm trying to solve is `y = 1/ c*exp(-b*x)` in the linear form. I have bunch of `y_data` and `x_data`, I want to get optimal values for `c` and `b`.

Comment: Just edited the equation.

Comment: You should clarify what problem are you really trying to solve, before worrying about the implementation. Are trying to solve the equation exp((1-Y)/Y) = exp(c) -b*x for which variable?

Comment: `np.exp(c)` is just another constant in this case, so you can replace it just by `C`. Could you add some data?!

Comment: Your first statement is an equation, not a function. If you put this equation to wolfram.alpha you will get an analytical solution, say for `Y`. You can then use numpy/matplotlib  to plot the result (careful, it's complex and it has multiple solutions).

Comment: @Cleb just added some data points.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r the function  I'm trying to solve is y = 1/ c*exp(-b*x) in the linear form. I have bunch of y_data and x_data, I want to get optimal values for c and b..

Comment: @CodeMAK: Ok, I added an answer below; let me know whether that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems with your code have already been pointed out. Here is a solution:

First, you need to get the correct logarithmic expression of your original function:

```
y = 1 / (c * exp(-b * x))
y = exp(b * x) / c
ln(y) = b * x + ln(1/c)
ln(y) = b * x - ln(c)
```

If you want to use that in `curve_fit`, you need to define your function as follows:

```
def f_log(x, b, c_ln):
    return b * x - c_ln
```

I now show you the outcome for some randomly generated data (using `b = 0.08` and `c = 100.5`) using the original function and then also the output for the data you provided:

```
[  8.17260899e-02   1.17566291e+02]
```

[image]

As you can see the fitted values are close to the original ones and the fit describes the data very well.

For your data it looks as follows:

```
[-0.094 -1.263]
```

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def f(x, b, c):
    return 1. / (c * np.exp(-b * x))


def f_log(x, b, c_ln):
    return b * x - c_ln

# some random data
b_org = 0.08
c_org = 100.5
x_data = np.linspace(0.01, 100., 50)
y_data = f(x_data, b_org, c_org) + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, len(x_data))

# fit the data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x_data, y_data, p0=(0.1, 50))
print popt

# plot the data
xnew = np.linspace(0.01, 100., 5000)
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'bo')
plt.plot(xnew, f(xnew, *popt), 'r')
plt.show()

# your data
x_data = np.array([4, 6, 8, 10])
y_data = np.array([0.86, 0.73, 0.53, 0.3])

# fit the data
popt_log, pcov_log = curve_fit(f_log, x_data, y_data)
print popt_log

# plot the data
xnew = np.linspace(4, 10., 500)
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'bo')
plt.plot(xnew, f_log(xnew, *popt_log), 'r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: In using the function:
 
def f_log(x, b, c_ln):
      return b * x - c_ln

should the y_data be converted to ln(y_data)?

Comment: @CodeMAK: Yes, you need to convert the data again. Did you already provide logarithmic data?

Comment: no, the y data given were not converted to log values

Comment: Ok, then you have to do this first and then convert them back again. You can also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903506/scipy-curve-fit-fails-power-law/35905257#35905257 for a similar example.

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that jump at me:

1. `ln((1-Y)/Y) = ln(c) -b*x` this is not valid Python code. On the left side you must have a name, whereas here you have a function call ln(..), hence the error.
2. `ln()` is not a Python function in the standard library. There is a `math.log()` function. Unless you defined `ln()` somewhere else, it will not work.

Comment: It seems you did not understand correctly the assignment statement, which is a pretty basic issue. You simply cannot have any form of `f(Y)=f(x,c,b)` type of assignment. On the left hand side of an assignment you can only have a name, without arguments: `g=f(x,c,b)` so g now contains the result of the evaluation of `f(x, c, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in defining function():

```
def function(x, b, c):

    ln((1-Y)/Y) = ln(c) -b*x
    return y
```

You're trying to assign

```
ln(c) - b*x
```

to the call of another function, ln(), rather than a variable.  Instead, solve the function for a variable (of the function) so it can be stored in a python variable.

Comment: Could you please show how to do this using the above function as an example